# Chessboard Display Error

Tags: amsart, chessboard, chess

When displaying chessboards using the [Chessboard](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chessboard/) Package, the border at the top of board does not line up with the actual top of the board. Relevant code and picture below. Thoughts?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}

\chessboard

\end{document}
```

[image: Chessboard Display Error]

Comment: @pgaf: The display is okay if one switches from `amsart` to `article`.

Comment: Then what does `amsart` do to make that look wrong?

Comment: I guess from the QED mark that the underlying implementation uses a theorem or similar. The AMS code alters a lot of math stuff, so this is the likely cause. I'd be tempted to report it to the package author.

Comment: @Joseph I think the QED is from `amsart`.  The `chessboard` package doesn't create any theoremlike environmnents. And if you load `amsthm` with `article` instead of `amsart` then the border is correct.

Comment: @Joseph @Alan The QED is just an indicator that White is to move. It comes from \chessboard, not from amsart.

Comment: @pgaf I have a problem with this ECM, without the package `skak' I get only the chessboard and not the pieces.

Comment: @Altermundus: It is normal that the board is empty when no chess page like skak or xskak is loaded. It is up to you to fill it.

Comment: @Ulrike Yes I understand but the ECM above from the OP is wrong, no ?

Comment: @Altermundus. The code of the ECM is fine, but the graphic doesn't show the output of this ECM.

Comment: @altermundus You are right--the graphic and the ECM are mismatched. I initially included \usepackage{xskak} in the ECM, but I edited it out when I realized the problem was with amsart and chessboard, not with xskak. I thought I included a note about this edit, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`amsart` has an additional lineskip which must be set to 0pt inside the chessboard:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xskak,chessboard}
\begin{document}

{\normallineskip=0pt
\setchessboard{smallboard,showmover=false}
\newchessgame
\chessboard}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. (The problem is not so much with `\normallineskip` which is non-zero in article too, but with `\normallineskiplimit`.) But I have no idea why it only affects amsart. Perhaps because amsmath is messing around with  arrays and this affect the `\parbox`. I will add a correction.

Comment: @Ulrike Very nice package for an old chess player like me!

Answer (score 4):

The style **amsbook** is also affected. The border at the top of board does not line up with the actual top of the board. The solution `\normallineskip=0pt` works equally in this case.